# flutter version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I was trying to do pub get command in my just newly created flutter project but it started giving this error:

```
D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in stock_exchange...                  
Because every version of flutter from sdk depends on meta 1.1.8 which doesn't match any versions, flutter from sdk is forbidden.

So, because stockexchange depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because stockexchange depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: stockexchange
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

flutter doctor result

```
D:\AndroidDevelopment\stock_exchange>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1039], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\SDK
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\SDK
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

flutter analyze:-

```
Because every version of flutter from sdk depends on meta 1.1.8 which doesn't match any versions, flutter from sdk is forbidden.
So, because stockexchange depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in stock_exchange...
pub get failed (1; So, because stockexchange depends on flutter any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

I have downloaded latest android studio 3.6, flutter and dart plugins, flutter sdk.
I don't have any idea to how to solve this issue can anyone help me?

Comment: Check it out: [Flutter 2 upgrade - Flutter version solving failed error](https://medium.com/@pratikbutani/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to the problem, I just needed to change the value of environment variable `PUB_HOSTED_URL` to https://pub.dev however it may depend on your location, for the correct value of the variable, if you don't have any idea then the best thing would be just to remove the variable and let flutter decide the URL automatically.